# Add drop down to widget if it is in a certain area

Tags: widgets

Is there a way to programmatically add a dropdown selector to any widget added to a given widget area?

I have a header widget area and I'd like any widget added to it to have a dropdown box with the option to align the widget to the left right or centre.  This would then be used to print a css class which would align the widget...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Widget CSS Classes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-css-classes/) is probably your best friend. It has the ability to add CSS classes manually by just typing them in, or you can set up predefined items that will add classes automatically. It's quite handy.